# Connection between Java and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to make a connection between Java and my data base. I am using Eclipse and xampp. I am almost convinced that I have good config of Eclipse and xampp, but maybe I missed something. I searched a lot on the Internet, but I have not found the solution.

My error are:

> SQLException: Could not create a connection to database server. Attempted to reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>   SQLState: 08001
>   VendorError: 0

1. Xampp - 
   [Xampp config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwJ63.png)
2. Eclipse - 
   I have jar files in the workspace folder.
   [Eclipse config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPkcy.png)
3. phpmyadmin - 
   I do not need a password to log into localhost/phpmyadmin and I have only one record in DB.
4. Code

   ```
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;

   public class JDBC2 {
   static String daneZBazy;
   static String polaczenieURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/heroes.db? 
   autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
   static String login = "root";
   static String password = "root";
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // Question to DB
   String query = "Select * FROM heroestab";

   Connection conn = null;

   try {

       // Connection parameters
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(polaczenieURL, login, password);

       //  MySQL Driver
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

       // Start question to DB
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       while (rs.next()) {
           wyswietlDaneZBazy(rs);
       }

       conn.close();
   }
   //throws exception
   catch (ClassNotFoundException wyjatek) {
       System.out.println("Driver error");
   }

   catch (SQLException wyjatek) {
       wyjatek.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("Login problem. Check, username, password, DB name, IP adress");
       System.out.println("SQLException: " + wyjatek.getMessage());
       System.out.println("SQLState: " + wyjatek.getSQLState());
       System.out.println("VendorError: " + wyjatek.getErrorCode());

      }

      }

       static void wyswietlDaneZBazy(ResultSet rs) {
       try {
       daneZBazy = rs.getString(1);
       System.out.println("\n" + daneZBazy + " ");
       daneZBazy = rs.getString(2);
       System.out.println(daneZBazy + " ");
       daneZBazy = rs.getString(3);
       System.out.println(daneZBazy);
       } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: The first thing to check is whether your MySQL local server is even up and running.  Can you connect to it from the command line, using the same port and credentials which the above Java code is using?

Comment: How should I do it ? I can ping my localhost, ane when I typed "C:\xampp\mysql\bin > mysql -u root -p " and I pressed Enter, I got info about "Distrib 10.1.37 for Win32 etc, and Variables and vlues.

Comment: I can see my databases useing cmd:
1. C:\xampp\mysql\bin > mysql -u root -p 
2. Enter
3. show databases ;
and then I can see all databases which I have on localhost. When i chose heroes and I can select * from heroes ;

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that both the **username and password are correct**.

I need the full stack trace from:

```
 wyjatek.printStackTrace();
```

If the username (root) and password are incorrect, you will see the below line in your stacktrace:

```
   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I remember correctly, with default xampp config, you can try this:

- user: root
- password: [blank]

> ```
> static String login = "root";
> static String password = "";
> ```

Comment: I set my login  and password in Java, as You said, and I got follow stack trace.

Full stack trace is here: https://pastebin.com/w8gqTd9p

Moreover I set it in cmd in "C:\xampp\mysql\bin > mysql -u root -p " and I pressed Enter.

Comment: I found it in your stacktrace: Unknown database 'heroes.db'. Please check your db name

Comment: Yes, I noticed that stacktrace, but I can see my databases useing cmd: 
1. C:\xampp\mysql\bin > mysql -u root -p 
2. Enter 
3. show databases ; and then I can see all databases which I have on localhost. When i chose heroes and I can select * from heroes ;

Comment: Using db name "heroes", not "heroes.db"

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I had to add  "serverTimezone=UTC" to my connection String, and I got fields from DB. I got the following message too:



" Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary."

Comment: Remove line: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

This message will be gone

Comment: When i removed: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); I have to add throws throws, and everything is working. Thank You a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can see my databases useing cmd:

> 1. C:\xampp\mysql\bin > mysql -u root -p
> 2. Enter
> 3. show databases ; and then I can see all databases which I have on localhost. When i
>      chose heroes and I can select * from heroes ;

Picture:
[Database cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSQWt.png)